# displaying image onLoadevent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a gif image for a few seconds before my home page is being displayed. I tried `onLoadEvent` with no success. Can someone suggest me the solution using CSS or JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: Show the code of what you've tried with `onLoadEvent` (which should have been `onload`, without the event BTW)... perhaps it's just a quick fix there

Comment: Hi, user####### and welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq so you can get help on 'how to ask for help' otherwise, your question might be down-voted for 'lack of effort' and removed by a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are looking for but this will show an image and hide it after 5 seconds on page load.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var imgContainer = document.getElementById('ImgContainer');
    imgContainer.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function () {
        imgContainer.style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
};
```

Here is a link to a JSFiddle example.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqtDe/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a div that fills the entire browser window with the image inside the div. In the bodys `onload` event (or if you are using jQuery `$(document).ready`) remove the div from the DOM.

Comment: adding div that fills the entire page won't work here. please see to it. http://jsfiddle.net/sqtDe/1/. Basically i want line 24 to 30 to pop up for a few seconds before the page. please suggest something.